# Not getting back the correct value from a multithreaded client server application

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

I'm currently working on a client server application where 2 clients have an oval on a JFrame and they can each see their position.

My problem is that when Client1 gets the position of Client2, he is not getting the correct value back because the opponent's oval position on the Frame is not right. I decided to have both oval moving downwards (increasing the y value) and print the oppYPos. It seems that when y = 250 its going back  to y = 4.

Im able to get the starting positions for both Clients and draw the oval on both windows, however when I run the thread, everything goes downhill from there...

Since I cant post pictures, here is some code:

This happens in the client thread: movePlayer, moves the oval down, checks for collision
and then sends the current x and y values to the server, the server then sets these new values as Opponent values for the second client and get the opp positions for the other client

```
            //This while loop is in the run method
    while(true){
        movePlayer();
        checkForCollisions();
        sendValuesToServer();
        getOppValuesFromServer();
        repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(120);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


   public  void sendValuesToServer()
{
    try {
        outputToServer.write(myXPos);
        outputToServer.write(myYPos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public  void getOppValuesFromServer(){

    try {
        this.oppXPos = inputFromServer.read();
        this.oppYPos = inputFromServer.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Here is the server side

```
       //The xStartPos are overriden by the new x and y values from the client
             while (true) {
        synchronized (this) {

            // Getting the new variables back
            try {
                xStartPos = inputFromClient.read();
                yStartPos = inputFromClient.read();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        // Setting the new values for opponents
        synchronized (this) {
            for (SnakeServerThread sst : snakeThreads) {

                if (sst != this) {
                    currentOppXPos = sst.xStartPos;
                    currentOppYPos = sst.yStartPos;
                }

            }
        }

        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                outputToClient.write(currentOppXPos);
                outputToClient.write(currentOppYPos);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

This works fine till the y value is 250...for some reason, it sets it to zero and the opponents just disappears half way through the screen and starts from the top.

Sorry if I included too much, but I've been trying to figure this out for the past 2 hours and no luck!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This works fine till the y value is 250...for some reason, it sets it to zero and the opponents just disappears half way through the screen and starts from the top.

Your problem is most likely that you are trying to write an integer to the server but [`OutputStream.write(byte)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28int%29) just looks at the lowest 8 bits of the value.  To quote from the javadocs:

> Writes the specified byte to this output stream. The general 
>   contract for `write` is that one byte is written 
>   to the output stream. The byte to be written is the eight 
>   low-order bits of the argument `b`. The 24 
>   high-order bits of `b` are ignored.

As soon as you exceed the 8 bytes of the byte you are rolling over to 0 again.  You need to write multiple bytes if your values are above 255.  You should write your position as a series of bytes:

```
...write(pos & 0xFF);
...write((pos & 0xFF00) >> 8);
// if the position can be more than 2 bytes
//...write((pos & 0xFF0000) >> 16);
//...write((pos & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
```

and then:

```
pos = ...read();
pos |= ...read() << 8;
// if the position can be more than 2 bytes
// pos |= ...read() << 16;
// pos |= ...read() << 24;
```

Something like that.  Or you could use serialization and write a `short` or an `int` directly.

Comment: Thank you!! I can't believe that was the problem, been trying for ages!

Comment: Sure @Legacy.  I've just edited my answer so make sure you reload.